# Determine AC Motor wiring (again)

Tags: motor, ac, phase

I have this air extractor which has an AC motor with multiple speeds.

- It has 4 wires (Yellow, Black, Blue, White).
- I know for sure that the yellow wire is connected to the LIVE on AC 220V
- It has a capacitor which is directly connected to Yellow wire on one end and I can't tell the other end. I measured resistance and got continuity from yellow to cap and no other cable showed continuity, all showed some resistance.

I've taken measurements on every wire pair like every tutorial out there said.
Here it is.

- Yellow + Black = ~120 Ohms
- Yellow + Blue  = ~80  Ohms
- Yellow + White = ~100 Ohms
- Black  + Blue  = ~45  Ohms
- Black  + White = ~25  Ohms
- Blue   + White = ~20  Ohms

I went ahead disconnected the capacitor and measured the wire that is not connected to yellow cable to each other cable and this is what I got.

- Brown + Yellow = 180 Ohms
- Brown + Black  = 140 Ohms
- Brown + Blue   = 100 Ohms
- Brown + White  = 120 Ohms

On the Air extractor, those wires go to a controlling board that has the following connections

- Yellow = Live
- Blue   = Triac -> Neutral
- Black  = Triac -> Neutral
- White  = Not connected to anything

I tried connecting the Yellow to Live and Black to Neutral and the motor didn't start. Then I swapped to White to Neutral and it didn't start either... I was expecting the motor to start on max speed and low speed

I have no schematics, model nor wiring diagram.. Could someone help me figure out what's the proper way to power the motor without the controller board?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I was right in my first assumptions.

- Yellow is Live
- Blue is the highest speed.
- White is the second speed.
- Black is the lowest speed.

My problem was the way I was "connecting the wires".. I was using a sonoff relay which is rated for 10A max and weird enough it doesn't turn on the motor. Joining Black and Neutral turned on the motor just fine.
I was  using the relay in the first place so I didn't have to connect everything on the fly. I was being extra cautious and that backfired :P